# Kotlin how to use this in "return (object : interface) { }"

Tags: kotlin

```kotlin
class AImpl : A {
    override fun createB(): B {
        return object : BImpl {
            val t = this

            override fun createC(): C {
                return CBuilderInstance.buildC { // this: CBuilder
                    this.B = t // type: B
                    // How can I use 'this@Something' to replace the t.
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

class CBuilder {

    fun buildC(block: CBuilder.() -> Unit): C {
        ...
    }

}
```

Sorry that I cannot describe the problem I met.

What can I do to replace "t" in the code?
The IDE give me 2 suggestions, "this" and "this@AImpl", which is not working for this.

Comment: You can make `val t` local to `createC`, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Kotlin Language Specification - This-expressions](https://kotlinlang.org/spec/expressions.html#this-expressions), a labeled this-expression can have the following forms:

- `this@type`
- `this@function`
- `this@lambda`
- `this@outerFunction`

The last 3 forms refer to the implicit receiver of functions/lambdas, which is obviously not what you want. You want to refer to the object created by the object literal `object : BImpl { ... }`.

The spec says (emphasis mine):

> `this@type`, where `type` is *a name of any classifier* currently being declared (that is, this-expression is located in the inner scope of the classifier declaration), refers to the implicit object of the type being declared;

And also in [Classifier Declarations](https://kotlinlang.org/spec/declarations.html#classifier-declaration), it says,

> Important: object literals are similar to object declarations and are considered to be *anonymous* classifier declarations, despite being expressions.

So although object literals are classifier declarations, they do not have a name that we can write after the `@`.

To conclude, you cannot use a labeled this expression here, without also changing something else.

You can, for example, declare a local class, which has a name:

```
class AImpl : A {
    override fun createB(): B {
        class Foo : BImpl {
            override fun createC(): C {
                return CBuilder.buildC {
                    this.B = this@Foo
                }
            }
        }
        return Foo()
    }
}
```